# rails rake access applications controller method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 3 rake task where I would like to execute a method in the applications controller.

Applications controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def jobplan_to_workorder(jobplan,woschedule)
    ...
  end
  helper_method :jobplan_to_workorder
...
```

1) lib/tasks/schedular.task :

```
...
jobplan_to_workorder(jobplan.id,@woschedule.id)
...
```

I get: undefined method `jobplan_to_workorder' for main:Object

2) lib/tasks/schedular.task :

```
...
ApplicationController.jobplan_to_workorder(jobplan.id,@woschedule.id)
...
```

I get: undefined method `jobplan_to_workorder' for ApplicationController:Class

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bad logic here. In rake tasks you should perform some business logic operations. And it's should not depend on you view context.

But if you want to do it you can do it like this:

```
controller = ApplicationController.new
controller.jobplan_to_workorder(jobplan.id, @woschedule.id)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I use the same code from a view - it's a button to execute it.  I didn't want to duplicate the code.